# Remove string from a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have  a dataframe of 2 columns. I need remove words on mutliple conditions.

1. if length of string in Text column is equal to 1
2. if Text corresponding Associated_word column has blank
3. Remove rows from the dataframe if Text column contains only number

**Input**

```
Text             Associated_word

Corperation      Corp., Coperate
f                flat,flt,flaat
100              200,30,40
block
24fl             24floor,25fl,36fl
central          centre, cent
20               30,40
```

**Output**

```
Text             Associated_word
Corperation      Corp., Coperat
24fl             24floor,25fl,36fl
central          centre, cent
```

**My code**

```
df= df[~df['Associated_word'].isnull()] 
df['Text']= (df['Text'].str.len() == 1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: @James,  `df= df[~df['Associated_word'].isnull()] 
df['Text']= (df['Text'].str.len() == 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the composition of all of your conditions with a bit-wise logical or. You can achieve this with a `numpy.logical_or.reduce`:

```
import numpy as np
conditions = [
    df['Associated_word'].isnull(),
    df['Text'].isnumeric(),
    df['Text'].str.len() == 1
]
df = df[np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
```